# Why did a moderator delete an on-topic question with a well-received answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I had an accepted answer on the question:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569512/how-to-denote-line-segment-lengths-of-a-triangle/569522#569522

My answer is two years old and suddenly OP does not like it anymore. My answer was un-accepted and OP wants me to delete it citing ridiculous reasons. OP wants to use the figure in a thesis and believes that in OP's non-specified country it is not allowed to show a figure with a circle and lines, if it already exists on the internet.

The figure is very generic - a circle and a couple of lines and labels:

[image: Circle with lines and labels]

How is a moderator willing to help OP by deleting a question from this site? The question has a title, that could help others find the relevant information, so it hurts the site.
I am also not amused - first my answer is vandalised and now deleted together with the question.

Comment: Given that it may interest others, you can ask a similar question and post your original answer.

Comment: Related: [Q145883](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/145883/revisions) and my [A145986](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/145986/revisions) where OP just replaced information in both the question and answer with dummy text. Q&A are still there (as is the history). A little bit different than your case since in my case it was more about placing a bunch of nodes instead of … geometry. Maybe the instructions to MWE should be revised and questioners should be instructed to anonymize their Q, though that wouldn't have helped much in your case. ☹

Comment: Is this graphic his or yours?

Comment: @stackprotector The graphic is the from the answer

Comment: So the discussed OP wants to delete [hpekristiansen's](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8650/hpekristiansen) graphic to be able to publish it as his? Wow...

Answer (score 24):

Let's not mince words; the OP at least *appears* to be attempting to commit academic fraud. It seems they are trying to pass off hpekristiansen's work as their own, and asking for the evidence of this to be removed from the internet. I would argue that this is academically really quite serious, especially since academic integrity, knowing how to reference outside material and give appropriate credit, and building on the work of others are all crucial research skills and important parts of what a thesis is supposed to demonstrate.

The mod says in one of his comments that "the presumption is to look favourably at the request unless there is a strong reason not to". **I believe academic fraud is a strong reason not to.** Even if it's just a simple diagram (and that's what's so incredible about this - one can construct a diagram like that in about the same time than it took to write this answer) the OP is demonstrating an overt lack of good faith. I would argue that too ought to diminish the weight of their request, since it undermines the integrity of the site.

As I think someone mentioned in one of the comments on this page, I would suggest to the author of the answer to post an equivalent question, along with their answer. I'd then go further, and cite/link this thread somewhere on there. That way the bad faith party will be forced to either acknowledge the work, or make their own diagram, since a Google image search of 'their' image will immediately discover the thread, and its true origin.

Comment: In addition to the possibility of serious problems with academic honesty, there might also be a violation of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license, under which the answer was posted, at play....

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm not sure that this is the case; in order to qualify for copyright a work has to meet a threshold of originality (this is why many well-known brand logos are not protected by copyright, only by trademark law) and I would not think that this figure meets that threshold (though I am not a lawyer). I think it is correct to frame it as a sign of bad faith instead.

Comment: For the same reason I would not have thought that attribution was necessary (no copyright means no license restrictions). The questioner's behavior points to bad intentions though, which is academically problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I am the moderator who took action here.

It is a long-standing approach on the site that one of the things to bear in mind with moderator decisions is that each post has an association with an original author. This is visible for example in  the history and on the main page as linked to the post. That means that their view has particular weight over-and-above 'general community standing'. This comes up from time to time where requests are made to delete questions which have answers posted that have a positive score: something the questioner ('OP') cannot do.

In the case at hand, the OP asked for redaction of the question and the answer to remove some information. As you note, the question here does not contain personal information and thus redaction did not make sense. However, they remained very unhappy about the presence of the question on the site. I therefore had to weigh up their right as the person with their name on the question against the wider considerations, in particular your time in answering and the community usefulness of the answer posted. I took the view that the usual balance applied, and that the right of the OP to request removal therefore took priority.

I am sure that the other moderators will review this decision in light of your post: they will have been notified of the presence of this new meta post.

---

Note that as a moderator, I am following established community norms in acting here and elsewhere. The community over time can and does evolve those norms. So if the consensus is that OPs should have less say in controlling their posts, that will inform future decisions on individual actions.

---

Following the discussion here, I have undeleted the post. It is clear that the community feeling is that the OP here is likely exceeding their rights in wanting the content to be removed.

Comment: Not directly relevant as an answer, but the edits to your post were made either the the OP or were rollbacks by another community member to _undo_ the edits made by the OP. There were no edits of your post made by moderators.

Comment: I think these things are handled by Stack Exchange's staff? Or just by moderators? (difficult decision...)

Comment: There's also the point that everything posted to Stack Exchange are licensed under CC-BY-SA so the author doesn't really have the right to demand it to be removed I think.

Comment: @user202729 The staff do very little moderation, as far as I know. Action by them is needed for account deletion for high-rep users, and also would be required to have an entire question removed from the database.

Comment: @user202729 Indeed: legally the OP can't _demand_ removal, but moderators can consider a request. That's what I'm trying to get at with the point about balancing different people's rights. (If the OP has posted something they do not have the right to license under CC-BY-SA, then things are different. That likely would be a staff-action situation.)

Comment: The usual course of action when somebody doesn't want their name on the question is to disassociate the post from their account, not deleting it. Was this considered as an alternative? Or did you judge the reason of the OP for requesting deletion (as I understand they cannot use a figure in their thesis if that figure can be found online) to be valid? That is a bit of a slippery slope IMO, if anything their name _should_ be on the post to show their thesis advisor that they asked help in making a figure, which is a completely acceptable action when writing up results.

Comment: @Marijn Deleting the user affects all of their posts, so is much less targetted than removal of a single post. Also, a decision to delete an account would need to come from the OP other than in cases of abuse (spam, self-promotion, etc.). As I hope I have made clear, I do not think the OPs concern about their thesis is a grounds for action _per se_, it is that the OP has an enhanced 'say' over their own posts compared to other users.

Comment: @Marijn "if anything their name should be on the post to show their thesis advisor that they asked help in making a figure, which is a completely acceptable action when writing up results." ... and even more importantly: the should give credit to the creator of the image in their thesis! In the now deleted comments they rejected the suggestion to modify the image for their thesis in order to workaround whatever problem they have with using it, as this would be too much work. So they apparently use an unmodified version of the image.

Comment: @JosephWright I did not mean deleting the whole user, just remove their name from this specific post, leaving all their other posts and their profile intact. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa: "If you would like to have your name disassociated from one of your posts, you can request we do so by clicking on the Contact link at the bottom of the respective page. Your username will no longer be linked and will be shown as 'anon' on the post."

Comment: Couldn't the question also have been made Community Wiki? In my opinion, this would create a separation between the OP and the post similar to deletion (sure, the information is still there, but that's also the case after deletion for users with more than 10k rep) but preserve the question and its answers for the community.

Comment: @Marijn That's true but feels to me like a different case - where an OP is happy for the material to remain but not to be linked to it. Here, we are starting with the idea of taking account of the OP's view on material they have posted, and where they want it removing.

Comment: @schtandard Much the same as I've just said to Marijn: it's quite true that can happen, but it's a solution to a different case. Here, the OP wanted the material removed, and as they posted it, the presumption is to look favourably at the request unless there is a strong reason not to.

Comment: @JosephWright I understand the OP wanted the material to be removed, but my comment was based on your argument in this answer that the "post has someone's name attached" and "the person with their name on the question". If this is indeed the main issue (the name being attached) then the preferred solution would be a single-post disassociation I think. If the reason actually was "the OP wanted the post removed" then your answer uses the wrong justification.

Comment: I do understand though that you might mean "their name on the question" somewhat figuratively as in "a post authored by a particular person" regardless of whether the name is actually visible or not.

Comment: @Marijn I mean that the user has their name attached, and unless they decide to have that link broken, by local convention they an additional say over the presence of the content on the site. A user wanting the material removed is unlikely to ask the staff to simply remove their name from the content.

Comment: @JosephWright I understand that the user did not ask to have their name removed (or be happy with that outcome). My point is that you said "their name is on the post so they have more rights" but you meant "they authored the post so they have more rights", or maybe even "they started the post so they have more rights". This is confusing, because while "their name on the post" can be fixed by removing the name, but "they authored it" can only be fixed by deleting or substantially rewriting, and "they started it" can only be fixed by deleting.

Comment: I guess I can get behind this convention in the sense of "the post author should, in principal, have editorial control of their post", I don't really see that it applies here. After all, the question OP did not really want their question removed but rather the helpful answer to it. My feeling is that the convention (in the aforementioned sense) should give precedence to the wishes of the answer author in that case. (Especially if the goal is to avoid giving credit.)

Comment: (In general I think this editorial control should not extend to removing posts from the site for personal, external reasons. But this general statement is maybe a separate discussion.)

Comment: @Marijn I have tried to clarity here

Comment: @schtandard The OP of the linked question wanted the question and answer to be redacted, something which did not make sense. That left me, as a mod, with two possible actions. The first was to refuse the OP entirely, probably requiring locking the question. The second was to delete the post. To me, the balance felt like it remained with the OP to ask for content to be removed. I have asked the other mods to review here.

Comment: (Honestly I don't see the point of discussing this issue other than to avoid creating a slippery slope...)

Comment: @user202729 I was asked to explain a moderating decision: it's entirely reasonable that decisions can be examined fully and that the wider community can understand how they happen and comment on whether they are in accord with expectations.

Comment: @JosephWright I have to say your edit doesn't clarify your argument much. You still talk about having somebody's name attached to a post, visible in the history and on the main page, while this is easily resolved by _removing their name from the post_. The main issue here is that you argued that the original author may request their question and associated answers to be removed if they have a good reason for this. While I don't necessarily disagree with that, it has nothing to do with their name being visible on the post or not.

Comment: @Marijn I think we are slightly at cross purposes. I'm trying to get at that as there is a name linked to the post, that name gets certain rights. Yes, they could ask to be unlinked, but that would be counter-productive for the case where they want to _exercise_ those rights to have a post edited or removed. Breaking the link addresses a very different issue from using the link to request certain actions.

Comment: Once one or more flags were raised, a moderator had to decide. No action would also be a decision. I think and see that Joseph considered and weighted it and also explained it here. Sometimes it's not perfect for everybody. Strange situation with that post and request though admitted. The post title "Moderator vandalize site" is, in my opinion, not justified. It looks like clickbait and pouring oil on a fire, so that's not a good start of evaluating what we should do in such a situation. Seeing that title, I appreciate Joseph's open, honest, and understandable explanation.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question, but if it was for plagiarism, wasn't it enough to delete the image and leave the code?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Perhaps because, in other situations, the moderators have not been so diligent.

Comment: @CarLaTeX The OP didn't ask about removing just the image, they also wanted the code altering

Comment: @JosephWright I think it is mostly a wording problem. I agree with you that the author of a post has certain rights (although in this particular case I don't think the reason to request deletion was 100% valid). The wording problem is that you say that they have rights because their name is on the post. This is not correct (imo). Correct would be to say that they have rights because they wrote the post. This is a very different thing, and the cause of the confusion for me.

Comment: @Marijn I've tried again to clarify: I guess the thing for me is that 'attached' means 'they wrote it', like a byline in a paper.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I'm not sure what you are referring to: perhaps one for another meta question?

Comment: @JosephWright If you write on the internet, 8 billion people can read it! How can you expect it to be kept secret? What if everyone ask to delete their posts? It is the OP's responsibility to anonymize what they write.

Comment: @JosephWright I'm referring to old stories that are better not to dig up.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes and I made that entirely clear to the OP: the question for me as a mod was to what extend do we _insist_ that all posts cannot be removed. For a single post with a relatively 'straight-forward' answer, etc., I made the judgement that _in a single case_ I would remove the post. There is a judgement call to make whenever we are asked to remove anything (and I would emphasis that here the OP did not request deletion of the entire post, but that this seemed the least worse solution.)

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I edited the title to be more neutral, hopefully hpekristiansen will agree with this change.

Comment: Is my reading correct that the question is not locked so could be undeleted via normal site mechanisms if 3 people choose to so vote?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not sure this would work https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233466/237989 ...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hmm not surprised that would be blocked I was surprised the undelete link appeared to be active (although I did not try it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If the overall community feeling is that deletion is not appropriate, the removal can of course be reversed

Comment: @JosephWright sure I just wondered if normal site processes could determine that but probably not. In any case given the unstable edit cycle probaby you can't simply undelete unfortunately.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If the post is undeleted, I think we will have to lock it

Comment: Thank you for restoring hpekristiansen's answer!

Comment: Upvoted your answer.

Comment: +1: In hindsight it is always easier to say :).